# How can I call a function from one component when a button in another component is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

Hi Guys I am a newbie in React-native I will like to know How I can called  a function of one component when a button in another component is click like below I will like to call the `onPlayPress()` function from PlayWidget component when the button in AlbumHeader get click on

AlbumHeader.tsx file

```
export type AlbumHeaderProp = {
    album: Album;
}

const AlbumHeader = (props: AlbumHeaderProp) => {

    const { album } = props;
  
    const playallSong = () => {

    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={playallSong}>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText} >
                        <PlayerWidget onPress={playallSong}/>
                        {Play}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
    )
}

export default AlbumHeader;
```

PlayWidget.tsx files

```
 const onPlayPausePress = async () => {
        if (!sound) {
            return;
        }
        if (isPlaying) {

            await sound.pauseAsync();
        } else {
            await sound.playAsync();
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of a use case for an observer pattern.

In the observer pattern there is a particular event that an "observer" cares about in the "publisher" (There are other names used for these things).

To sum it up, the "observer" (sometimes called "Subscriber") is the one who needs to be called when an event occurs. The "Publisher" or "Observable" is the one who will do the calling of all subscribers when a particular event occurs.

The "publisher" will have an "on" or "subscribe" function that registers the observer to be called for the particular event.

Here is a great post for more about the Observer Pattern
[Refactoring Guru - Observer](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer)

### How does it help you?

your code will look something like the following...

```js
interface AlbumHeaderProps {
    // ...
    onPlayerWidgetPress(): Promise<void> // analogous to .subscribe(Observer)
}

const AlbumHeader = ({
    onPlayerWidgetPress,
}: AlbumHeaderProps) => {

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
    // ...
            <PlayerWidget
                onPress={onPlayerWidgetPress}
            />
    // ...
        </View>
    )
}
```

Then in the code that calls this component...

```
<AlbumHeader
  onPlayerWidgetPress={async () => { // analogous to .update() method on observer
    //... your function
  }}
/>
```

NOTE: I don't know how or if PlayerWidget honors/awaits promises so I can't speak to concurrency control here.

Your final solution may vary, but hopefully this helps to get you part of the way there.

Comment: Still can't understand how this relate to my question but thank any way I believe you could have told me how to apply such pattern to the above code

Comment: no problem, my advice is take a closer look... It's in how you wire the pieces together.

"...when the button in AlbumHeader get click on" .. that's the key part in the question

------

If I get a chance today, I'd be happy to write a test that confirms this solution works...

Comment: @GeorgeSMulbahII

Maybe it would be worth saying...

no function is actually being passed


<PlayerWidget onPress={}/>

Comment: bro I am starting to seeing the logic in what you where talking about but still a little confuse here please bro could you elaborate more on this pattern

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the function as prop to the component with the button. Then when you click the button, you can call that function

Component A - has function

Component B - has button

Assuming Component B is a child of Component A - then `<Component B func={compAFunc}/>`

Then in Component B button's onClick method

```
<btn onClick={props.func} />
```

If B is not a child of A, then you will probably have to lift state up to another component. Otherwise add the function to a global store like redux so it can be shared all over.